# rsync: ERROR: at most 20 --compare-dest args may be specified

Tags: rsync

When I execute the following `rsync` command

```
rsync -avh --compare-dest=/opt/dest/Init/ --compare-dest=/opt/dest/{01..20}/ /opt/src /opt/dest/21
```

I get below error

```
Error:
rsync: ERROR: at most 20 --compare-dest args may be specified.
```

How to avoid this error if I have more than 20 directories in `--compare-dest` argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit is hard coded [in the source](https://git.samba.org/?p=rsync.git;a=blob;f=rsync.h;h=53fff2d630f4a1f7036d06c01459c58698906381;hb=eec6ab7615535e02cfcb691d44575268bdcf656f#l151) (`#define MAX_BASIS_DIRS 20`).

You can increase the number and build rsync yourself.